# Webview.loadurl from another class

Tags: android, webview, onclick

I've set up my webview like this

```
public class Webview extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Chargement en cours", true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String ur){ 
                pd.dismiss();
              }
            });



    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");


}
```

and i have another class MainActivity like that

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
}

public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Webview.class);
    switch(v.getId()) {     

    case R.id.button1:
        intent.putExtra("url", "http://www.google.fr");
    break;      
    case R.id.button2:
        intent.putExtra("url", "http://www.orange.fr");
    break;

       //and so on....

  }
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

}

here is an extract of mainactivity layout  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
   android:id="@+id/frontpage_view"
android:tag="front"
 >

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/actualites"
        android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
        android:text="Actualités"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:background="@null"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/agenda"
        android:text="Agenda"
        android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@null" />
```

I've got he message webview cannot be resolved , do i need to declare the webview in themainactivity too ?
how would i do that?

Comment: First of all I don't think it's a good way to use your class name as `Webview`.

Comment: Where you have defined webview in xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access webview which is not in MainActivity.java. So you are getting this error. What you should do on button click is:

1. Pass url according to clicked button in intent to Webview.java
2. Load url in webview accordingly in sencond activity.

Pass url as per clicked Button:

```
switch(v.getId()) {


    case R.id.button1:
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Webview.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", "http://www.google.fr");
        startActivity(intent);
    break;      
    case R.id.button2:
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Webview.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", "http://www.google.fr");
        startActivity(intent);
    break;

       //and so on....

  }
```

In your Webview.java:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Chargement en cours", true);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }   
});
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Hope this is clear.

Comment: thanks but i'm having error on the switch : Syntax error on token { SwitchLabels expected after this token ?

Comment: @MuiMui yes. Check edit. Switch should be followed by case. Move intent line above switch statement.

Comment: i've tried that, but now the startActivity(intent); returns : unreachable code, sorry to bother i'm a beginner

Comment: @MuiMui Put startActivity after switch case block.

Comment: @MuiMui Please edit your question with more code. This code works fine in my app,

Comment: webview seems to load, but sounds like i'm reaching a blank page

Comment: @MuiMui Network connection might be slow. Have you added permission Internet in manifest? And reconnect wifi.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />         is added to my manifest yes.  disconnected reconnected wifi severals time, still blank, strange                                EDIT : i've added a progressdialog, other links to see whats going on, it keeps loading for ever

Comment: @MuiMui can you edit your question with latest code? With progress dialog part?

Comment: done, strange thing, also other button (4,5,6...) are not in the switch case, when you click on one of them, it load something (still blank)

Comment: @MuiMui See the WebViewClient code first in edit. You need to use @Override notation. Plus, you had not wrote `webview.loadUrl` line in your code, so `onPageFinished` was never being called. And check switch case edit for problem you mentioned in last comment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call loadUrl from MainActivity as you have not declared in it.
You need to start your webview activity from here and in the intent pass the url to load.

Answer (score 0):

You will need start your Webview Activity and pass url to that.

So, to start your WebView Activity you will need

```
switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.button1:
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebView.class);   
    i.putExtra("URL", "http://www.google.fr");
    startActivity(i);
    break;      
    case R.id.button2:
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebView.class);   
    i.putExtra("URL", "http://www.google.fr");
    startActivity(i);
    break;

   //and so on....
  }
}
```

and in your WebView Activity

```
webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getExtras().getString("URL"));
```

Don't forget to put WebView Activity in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

The code is perfectly fine.
Just change `String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(url);`
and after this in the next line just add `webView.loarUrl(url);`.
It worked for me.